# UML, Java and ArrayList

Tags: java, oop, generics, jakarta-ee, uml

I have an UML diagram and I don't really know how I should read it :

[image]

I don't know if I should put the arraylist in ModeTransport or Transports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your  `ArrayList<Transport> liste;` should be in `Transport` if generate diagramms from code, move liste to this class (Transport).

If you generate code from UML you should check the association and correct the direction.